# VAO and VBO Crashing when drawing

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, vao

I changed my code from DisplayLists to VBOs / VAOs.
But when i run the application it crashes.

It crashes when at the first attempt to draw the VAOs. I'm drawing using no shaders (so it does not cause problems).

There are up to 12 faces (12 * 3 vertices) in one VAO and texture coordinates for those. There are up to 500 000 VAOs.

How i create a face:

```
tData.add(new float[]{textureX + 0.1249f, textureY+ 0.1249f});
vData.add(new float[]{x, y, z});
tData.add(new float[]{textureX+ 0.1249f, textureY+0.0001f});
vData.add(new float[]{x, y+1, z+1});
tData.add(new float[]{textureX+0.0001f, textureY+0.0001f});
vData.add(new float[]{x+1, y+1, z+1});
```

Creating the VBO/VAO:

```
if(vData.isEmpty())
        return;

    int vaoHandle = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

    int vertexDataSize = vData.size() * 3;
    int textureDataSize = tData.size() * 2;
    FloatBuffer vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vData.size() * 3);
    FloatBuffer textureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(tData.size() * 2);

    while(!vData.isEmpty())
    {
        vertexData.put(vData.remove(0));
    }
    while(!tData.isEmpty())
    {
        textureData.put(tData.remove(0));
    }

    vertexData.flip();
    textureData.flip();

    int vertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, vertexDataSize, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    int textureHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, textureDataSize, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    renderEngine.vaos.add(new VAO(vaoHandle, (int)((float)vertexDataSize / 3f)));
```

Rendering the VBO / VAO:

```
    glUseProgram(0);//TODO:REMOVE
    for(VAO vao : vaos)
    {
        glBindVertexArray(vao.getHandle());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        System.out.println(vao.getVertices());//correct numeber
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vao.getVertices());//<-- CRASH at first time called

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Here's the error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000b3fb610, pid=7736, tid=6224
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x8b610]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Geosearchef\workspaces\workspaceLWJGL\OrangeJuiceVBO\hs_err_pid7736.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I don't think it's sensefull to post the whole error here.
Do you have any idea why this is happening? I can't find anything about this error concerning VBOs.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what is VAO and how to use it??Why your program is unbound when you draw?Also why do you enable.disable attrib arrays during rendering?You must not do it when using VAO.You enable those once when setting up VAO.Shortly,read how to use VAO.

Comment: Ok, thx! Didn't know this, cause here it is shown before rendering: http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Quad_with_DrawArrays , but i think that's cause it's only renderd one time. I unbound my program when drawing to make sure it isn't my shader (glsl version 130, cause of display lists) that is causing the problems. I'll rewrite it and enable it when VBOs are working.

Comment: Look at this tutorial: http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl4/4-opengl-4-vao.html

Comment: Enabling/disabling attribs during rendering renders usage of VAO pointless.Do that step only once when you setup VAO or change its buffer attachments.During the drawing just bind/unbind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not set the vertex attribute pointers correctly:

```
int vertexDataSize = vData.size() * 3;
int textureDataSize = tData.size() * 2;
[...]
glVertexAttribPointer(0, vertexDataSize, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
[...]
glVertexAttribPointer(1, textureDataSize, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

The `size` parameter defines the number of elements in the vector of each vertex, and must be in the range of 1 to 4.

YOur code will just generate a GL error - and you should definitively add some error checks, at least for debugging - and leaves the attribute pointer uninitialized.

Another issue here: you use generic vertex attributes 0 and 1, but you don't use shaders. That is not going to work. The spec only guarantees that attribute index 0 will map to the classic `glVertex` attribute, but attribute 1 might be anything, or not work at all.

Comment: He does many more wrong things in his code.His usage of VAO in the drawing code is completely wrong.

Comment: The drawing code is not wrong in the strict sense. It is just inefficient.

Comment: I changed the VBO creation to make one VBO for each triangle, now it works. Thx for your help! I still don't understand what should be better with using VBOs compared to DisplayList. I've still 3 FPS (displaylist: 70). This is my second attempt with VBOs, same result. Am i doing something THAT ineficcent?

Comment: @Geosearchef: Your approch is totally inefficient. Having 500000 draw calls per frame won't be fast either. Your comparision with display lists would only be fair if you had 500000 display lists before. Using 2 separate VBOs _per triangle_ is never going anywhere. You seem to have misunderstood how VBOs work.

Comment: @derhass Now i have 256 VBOs containing the same number of polygons and still get 3 FPS.